# Is it worthy to learn Angular 2, when i know Symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, angular, frontend, backend

I know **Symfony 3**. In my opinion it is great organized framework. I am interested in connecting it with **Angular 2**, but have some doubts.

I start learning Angular 2 because I can see these **advantages**:

- Using Angular 2 + Ionic 2 I can create mobile app.
- Using single page concept I can maintain connection with web-sockets.
- Changing state of application i can modify view in real time.

But there are also **problems**, if I want to write back-end in Symfony 3 and fornt-end in Angular 2:

- I have code repetition (definition of classes, and these methods).
- I have problem with SEO connected with fact, that Angular is unfriendly for scrapers.
- I twice time type tests, routing, forms...

Of course I obtain **bonus** because:

- Back-end and front-end completely disconnected.
- Existing of API is forced in this approach.

But typing almost all app two times is high cost. Is there any manner to obtain advantages of single page application in Symfony 3, without Angular 2, or Is worthy to use Angular 2 although of mentioned disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the following decision before jumping to choosing technologies and tools.

**Server Side Rendering**: Does your App (current and future) and other conditions make a case for HTML fully constructed on the server side - Symphony

Vs.

**Client Side Rendering** : If App calls for HTML being rendered Client side - AngularJS

Collect all the facts about the application and future where it might lead to  and apply those pros and cons of the above two that you can research (Google/stackoverflow). And it will lead to your answers.
As a side note a lot more goes into than just the runtime dymanics of the App like maintainability, debug ability etc. You can find questions already answers to those - if not you can post it as a separate questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you worry about it.

If you see advantages in Angular2 (ionic framework + mobile app), then go for it !

Ang again, if you worry about the SEO, you should make two fronts : one in plain old HTML for the web version, and another with Angular for the mobile app.